# Para que un método sea óptimo en programación orientada a objetos ¿Debe tener una mínima cantidad de líneas de código?

Tags: php, optimización, poo

Tengo una clase en `PHP` con un método que contiene 260 líneas de código. Quiero saber si tener tal cantidad de líneas de código hace que mi aplicación no sea óptima.

Comment: Es difícil definirlo pues en realidad son consideraciones por programador, yo prefiero tener métodos con poco código siguiendo las mejores metodologías, usando patrónes de diseño y [DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas). De ser posible, factoriza.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Por favor toma el [tour] para que aprendas lo esencial sobre cómo funciona este sitio.

Comment: En vez de centrarte en las líneas de código, sería mejor hacerlo en que la clase haga su cometido correctamente.

Comment: Concuerdo con @Rubén. Cuando haya una cantidad de moderadores con puntajes altos generalmente este tipo de preguntas son cerradas ya que permiten discusiones interminables que no aportan al contenido del mismo.

Comment: @gersonZaragocin Bienvenido también a SOes. Tenemos varias discusiones en [meta] sobre como va a funcionar SOes. En algunas cosas va a ser diferente a [so] así que si no lo haz hecho aún, dale un vistazo a esas discusiones.

Comment: El número de líneas y lo óptimo de un código no tienen que ver una con otra, son cosas totalmente distintas

Comment: Voto por reabrir porque se han publicado algunas respuestas interesantes, pero debería ser wiki.

Comment: @Konamiman cerrar no es lo mismo que eliminar, si ya hay respuestas interesantes e incluso una respuesta aceptada la pregunta no se eliminará del sistema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si eres nuevo en desarrollo, tal vez no estés muy familiarizado con patrones de diseño, te podría recomendar [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/php/) como analizador de código para `PHP`:

http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/php/

Tiene reglas de código y metricas previamente definidas que aquí se en listan:
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=php

#### No existe métrica que defina cuantas lineas debe tener idealmente tu método,

pero existen consideraciones como:

- Evitar repetir código dentro de varios métodos o tener métodos repetidos.
- Es importante la modulación.
- Evitar complejidad ciclomática en los métodos
- Usar métodos del sdk los cuales ya fueron probados y aseguran no tener bugs, etc..

acerca de [**Complejidad Ciclómatica**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complejidad_ciclom%C3%A1tica)

Comment: Desafortunadamente, en América Latina nos enseñan que sí hay métricas basadas en KLOC: http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=198:calidad-del-software-metricas-y-fiabilidad-de-aplicaciones-1a-parte-dv00103a&catid=45:tendencias-programacion&Itemid=164 o http://sg.com.mx/content/view/717

Comment: Nos estamos refiriendo a cuantas lineas dentro de un método se deben tener.

Comment: La pregunta es acerca de su aplicación, no sobre su método, por lo cual esta respuesta está fuera de lugar.

Comment: Eres desarrollador web verdad? "Tengo una clase en PHP con un método que contiene 260 líneas de código".

Comment: No, para demérito de tu prejuicio me formé como científico computacional y me desenvuelvo en muchos campos. Existen métricas para Java aunque en PHP no lo sé por lo que deberías especificar. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_metrics.html#JavaNCSS ;)

Comment: Te reitero adicionalmente que la pregunta es acerca de su aplicativo, no de su método. "Quiero saber si tener tal cantidad de líneas de código hace que mi aplicación no sea óptima". Y si incluso, este no fuera el caso, tu respuesta "Evitar repetir código dentro de varios métodos o tener métodos repetidos." no se centra en un método, sino en todo el aplicativo.

Comment: Hey espera no creo que sea malo desarrollar para web, yo he sido desarrollador web, ok entonces eres científico =0!.

Answer (score 6):

Lo que sea que te haya hecho pensar que un código es óptimo por la cantidad de líneas, ¡déjalo ir!, en serio, tienes que sacarte esa idea de la cabeza desde ahora.

En lenguajes que han sido influenciados por el lenguaje C, como PHP en este caso, se usa el punto y coma (`;`) para separar las sentencias, pero incluso tu código de 260 líneas puede convertirse en 1 línea ya que es perfectamente posible continuar una sentencia detrás de otra sin hacer un salto de línea, ¿qué te parece esto?:

```
<?php class Person { public $firstName; public $lastName; public function __construct($firstName, $lastName = '') { $this->firstName = $firstName; $this->lastName  = $lastName; } public function greet() { return 'Hello, my name is ' . $this->firstName . (($this->lastName != '') ? (' ' . $this->lastName) : '') . '.'; } public static function staticGreet($firstName, $lastName) { return 'Hello, my name is ' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . '.'; } } $he = new Person('John', 'Smith'); echo $he->greet(); ?>
```

Es un extracto de una función ejemplo sacada de [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). ¿Acaso la version anterior es más óptima que esta?:

```
<?php
    class Person
    {
        public $firstName;
        public $lastName;

        public function __construct($firstName, $lastName = '') { // optional second argument
            $this->firstName = $firstName;
            $this->lastName  = $lastName;
        }

        public function greet() {
            return 'Hello, my name is ' . $this->firstName .
               (($this->lastName != '') ? (' ' . $this->lastName) : '') . '.';
        }

        public static function staticGreet($firstName, $lastName) {
            return 'Hello, my name is ' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . '.';
        }
    }

    $he = new Person('John', 'Smith');
    echo $he->greet();
?>
```

Pues no, son exactamente iguales.

Si realmente quieres tener código óptimo, puedes tener en cuenta:

- Un algoritmo robusto y eficiente
- [Desenvolvimiento de bucles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)
- [Fusión de bucles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fusion)
- [Distribución de bucles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fission)
- [Reuso de código](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse)
- [Reducción de esfuerzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction)

Patrones, principios, filosofías:

- [Refactoriza](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactorizaci%C3%B3n)
- [No te repitas (DRY)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas)
- [Usa el principio KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS)
- Comenta tu código (los demás programadores te lo agradecerán)
- [Usa patrones de diseño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)
- Haz pruebas, pruebas y más pruebas.

Y esto no tiene relación directa con PHP, son cosas en general que te pueden ayudar a optimizar tu código. En realidad, yo no se absolutamente nada de PHP.

Yo soy Pythonero, y me gustaría compartir contigo algunas partes del conocido **[Zen de Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)**:

> Hermoso es mejor que feo.
>
> Explícito es mejor que implícito.
>
> Simple es mejor que complejo.
>
> Complejo es mejor que complicado.
>
> Plano es mejor que anidado.
>
> Disperso es mejor que denso.
>
> La legibilidad cuenta.
>
> Cuando te enfrentes a la ambigüedad, rechaza la tentación de adivinar.
>
> Ahora es mejor que nunca.
>
> Si la implementación es difícil de explicar, es una mala idea.
>
> Si la implementación es sencilla de explicar, puede que sea una buena idea.

Continúa leyendo:

- [Optimización de software](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_de_software)

Comment: Me parece que lo que tu describes en tu respuesta es "buen código", no "código óptimo", los principios de POO y los patrones de diseño no fueron creados para ayudar a optimizar un código, sino para crear un código mas estructurado, más fácil de entender, etc

Comment: No me queda claro de qué forma hacer refactorización implica tener un código óptimo.

Answer (score 3):

La cantidad de lineas de código no hacen que tu método se óptimo o no, si no la complejidad algorítmica de este y el tiempo que demora su ejecución cuando lo invocas. 
La complejidad algorítmica se mide dependiendo la cantidad de datos que procesa y el número de estructuras repetitivas que tiene.

Answer (score 3):

La cantidad de líneas de código no determina si un programa es óptimo o no, la calidad del código sí. Puede haber programas cortos que sean terribles en ejecución y programas muy largos que sean eficientes como el kernel de Linux.

Lo que debes preguntarte es si existe separación de responsabilidades en tu programa. ¿Esas 260 líneas tienen bien repartida su funcionalidad en métodos o funciones o todo es un bloque de código que se ejecuta de principio a fin estilo C?

Otra consideración podría ser si estás usando algún paradigma en particular como Orientado a Objetos, patrones de diseño o un Framework, estos pueden incrementar el número de líneas, pero bien utilizados sin duda harán que la calidad de tu código mejore.

Por último hay detalles que si bien no tengan mucho impacto en la ejecución de tu programa ayudan durante el proceso de desarrollo como usar nombres de variables y métodos adecuados que especifiquen claramente su intención, o el uso sensible de comentarios. Esto ayuda en la legibilidad del código, porque seguramente en el futuro tú o alguien más lo leerá y tratará de entenderlo, los puntos anteriores facilitarán esta tarea.

Answer (score 2):

El número de lineas de código no es una buena medida que te permita verificar si es "óptimo".

Lo coloco entre comillas porque el término optimo puede tener varias connotaciones, por ejemplo a un código eficiente en términos de velocidad de ejecución, o a un código cuyo mantenimiento futuro pueda ser simple.

Como aprenderás con la experiencia varias de las medidas de verificación de si tienes buen código o no son incluso opuestas entre si. Por ejemplo la separación del código para que sea legible en métodos mas pequeños implica el uso de una cantidad mayor de memoria y posiblemente debido a las llamadas realizadas, el uso de algunos ciclos de procesador adicional mientras se ejecuta el programa, sin embargo yo personalmente prefiero codigo legible aunque penalizado de esa forma.

Dicho esto, el tamaño de un método, no debería exceder una cantidad de 20 a 25 lineas, y estar orientado a solucionar una sola tarea en especifico. A mi criterio un único método de 260 lineas necesita ser refactorizado (reestructurado) en varios métodos mas simples cuya función sea única.

Comment: Estoy desarrollando mi aplicacion con el patron de arquitectura MVC El método de 260 lineas esta en mi controlador es un manejador  de eventos que escucha el llamado de mis vistas , para cada vista hago un deferente proceso . a medida de que agrego mas vistas mi cogido crece he de hay 260 lineas ,  he pensando en crear un método para cada vista y así definir una solución especifica para cada vista. me preocupa es si esta bien o mal tener tantas lineas de código para un método.

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar debes especificar a que te refieres con ***óptimo***. Hay muchas cosas que se pueden optimizar, como la memoria, el tiempo de ejecución, el espacio en disco etc. y muchas veces son excluyentes entre sí.

Segundo: la cantidad de líneas de código no afecta tanto al programa en ejecución sino mas bien a la *mantenibilidad* del código fuente.

Ya que un método con tantas líneas va a hacer muy dificil su lectura y seguimiento, lo que te recomendaría que dividas el método en varias partes mas pequeñas que cumplan con un objetivo específico cada una.

Answer (score 1):

No te afanes en medir las líneas de código. Todo depende de la complejidad de la clase que estas desarrollando.

El trabajo de un programador debe medirse en eficacia y eficiencia, y medir líneas de código puede ser tan absurdo como medir el trabajo de un médico por el número de recetas extendidas en lugar de por la calidad de vida de sus pacientes.

Cuantas más líneas de código tiene un programa, más grande y complejo es -al menos en teoría-. Programas con muchas líneas de código fuente son también mucho más difíciles de mantener al día, y son más propensos a tener puntos débiles.

No puedes determinar si son pocas o muchas lineas si no sabes que hace tu código.